# test.mp3 isnt precompiled in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am building a site that makes use of the html5 audio tag. In my view I have added <% audio_tag "test.mp3", :controls => true %> and this works well in development. However when I deploy my app to Heroku and try access it I get this error in the logs **"ActionView::Template::Error (test.mp3 isnt precompiled)"**

How do I fix this?

Comment: where this file is placed in your app structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try specifying:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

in your `production.rb` file.

---

One more solution is to precompile your assets before pushing to `heroku` repo:

```
rake assets:precompile
git commit add .
git commit -a -m "Assets are precompiled"
git push heroku master
```

I can't test it now, but it should work.

Comment: This works but I would like to know if it is the only way out because the rails guides documentation states --> "This mode uses more memory, performs more poorly than the default and is not recommended."

Comment: @General_9 I've added one more approach to my answer. Please, disable `config.assets.compile` and check it.

Answer (score 0):

In production all of your files stored in assets directory are precompiled. When you are using  rails tag helpers like audio_tag asset pipeline expects that your assets is located in one of assets directory. To roll up with it you could use raw html tag:

```
<audio src="/audios/test.mp3" />
```

or place that file in app/assets directory. 
More info is available [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production)